# Update notification is not showing

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

I am developing a gallery plugin. So i created a custom post type and under it i created a submenu page for changing gallery options such a border-width, border-color, border-radius etc. when i update the values, all are working but update notification is not showing.
I am writing main code here. Please let me know what is problem.

```
function gallery_setting_pages() {
    add_submenu_page(
        'edit.php?post_type=gallary',
        'Gallery Settings',
        'Settings', 
        'manage_options', 
        'gallery-setting',
        'gallery_option_page_functions'
    );
    }
    add_action('admin_menu','gallery_setting_pages');


if ( is_admin() ) : 

    function ppmscrollbar_register_settings() {
    register_setting('gallery_plugin_options','rt_gallery_options','rt_gallery_validate_options');
    }

 add_action('admin_init','ppmscrollbar_register_settings');



function gallery_option_page_functions() {

    global $rt_gallery_options;

         if ( ! isset ($_REQUEST['updated'] ) )
            $_REQUEST['updated']=false; 
    ?>
        <?php if ( false !==$_REQUEST['updated'] ) : ?>
        <div class="updated fade"><p><strong><?php _e('options saved'); ?></strong></p></div>
        <?php endif; // If the form has just been submitted, this show the notification ?>

        <form method="post" action="options.php">

        <?php $settings=get_option( 'rt_gallery_options', $rt_gallery_options); ?>

        <?php settings_fields('gallery_plugin_options'); ?>

        <table class="form-table">

            <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row"><label for="cursor_color">Select Gallery Border Color</label></th>
                <td>
                    <input id="cursor_color" type="text" name="rt_gallery_options[cursor_color]"  value="<?php echo stripslashes($settings['cursor_color']); ?>" class="my-color-field" /><p class="description">In a few words, explain what is this.</p>
                </td>
            </tr>


            </table>

            <p class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="button button-primary" id="submit" name="submit"></p>    

          </form>   

        </div>
    <?php

    }

    function rt_gallery_validate_options( $input ){
       global $rt_gallery_options;

       $settings = get_option( 'rt_gallery_options', $rt_gallery_options );

       //We strip all tags from the text field, to avoid vulnerablilties like XSS

        $input['cursor_color']=wp_filter_post_kses( $input['cursor_color']);

        return $input;

    }
    endif;   //EndIf is_admin()
```

Answer (score -1):

thanks for being posted the question on stackoverflow to get answers. We are here to help you.Please mention the page name you are using above , and let me know where you are updating the variable "updated" in your page. The issue might be, if you are not setting the variable, then if condition always fails, and notification will not be shown.